# Undo the permutation by sort_by with random block in ruby

Tags: ruby, encryption, random

**I am trying to implement encryption & decryption in ruby**.
Consider 128,129 are seed keys.

Let's take

```
rows=["atta","ckat","dawn"] 

myrandom=Random.new(128) 
rows.sort_by!{myrandom.rand}

Output==>["dawn","ckat","atta"]

myrandom=Random.new(129)
rows.map!{|row| row.chars.sort_by{myrandom.rand}.join}.join 

Output==>nwadtkacaatt
```

My major concern is to undo this random permutation.By taking this below given string as input.

> nwadtkacaatt

```
   myrandom=Random.new(129)
   rows.map!{|row| row.chars.sort_by{myrandom.rand}.join}.join
```

And get back the this:-

`rows=["dawn","ckat","atta"]`

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to map the sorting order that we used to encrypt:

```
myrandom=Random.new(129)
mapping = 3.times.map { 4.times.sort_by { myrandom.rand } }
#  => [[3, 1, 0, 2], [3, 1, 2, 0], [1, 3, 0, 2]]
```

This is the same shuffle that was made on the input strings - "nadwtkactaat"

Now, we'll do the reverse sort to put each index back where it should be:

```
reverse =  mapping.map { |m| m.each_with_index.to_a.sort.map(&:last) }
# =>  [[2, 1, 3, 0], [3, 1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 3, 1]]
```

Now we'll apply the reverse shuffle on the input string:

```
3.times.map { |i| 4.times.map { |j| "nadwtkactaat"[i*4+reverse[i][j]] }.join }
# => ["dawn", "ckat", "atta"]
```